# SELinux httpd With custom app

Tags: permissions, httpd, selinux

I'm enabling SELinux on a server, and the httpd server (nginx and phusion passenger) is unable to read the app's dir (`/home/app`), with the following message:

```
#============= httpd_t ==============

#!!!! WARNING: 'home_root_t' is a base type.
#!!!! The file '/home/app/config.ru' is mislabeled on your system.
#!!!! Fix with $ restorecon -R -v /home/app/config.ru
allow httpd_t home_root_t:file { getattr open read };
```

I'd like to keep SELinux on, but enable this.

1. What command do I use to relabel `/home/app` so that httpd can read it?
2. Will this survive reboots?
3. I'd like this to be sticky, so that if I `rm /home/app` and put other content there (e.g. an app upgrade), I don't need to relabel it.
4. And of course it should apply to subdirs as well (`/home/app/sub`), both existing and future.
5. Finally, there are log files in `/home/app/log`, and I'll need rw access to it.  I'd be willing to allow rw access to the entire `/home/app` if necessary.

**How can I configure SELinux to work with my custom app?**

Comment: Don't try to use this policy. Instead run `restorecon` as the message advised you. Of course, you shouldn't have web sites in user home directories anyway; you're going to run into [further trouble](https://serverfault.com/a/779855/126632) after this.

Comment: Thank you Michael.  I'm studying the post you linked and its references, and will circle back.  I don't think `restorecon` alone, as advised by the message, will help, because it will hit similar errors with other files, no?